# Web scraping with Python - why I cannot get the table content?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the table content from LBMA website with the code below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.lbma.org.uk/membership/current-membership#-'

#send the request to the url
response = requests.get(url)
#parse the html content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find_all('table', class_ = 'panel border-collapse w-full')
print(table)
```

Code returnse empty object (<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see inside table is stored in `<script>` element. So to parse it you can use `re`/`ast.literal_eval`:

```py
import re
import requests
from ast import literal_eval

import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.lbma.org.uk/membership/current-membership#-"

html_text = requests.get(url).text
data = re.search(r"dataset = (.*?\])\s*<", html_text, flags=re.S).group(1)
data = literal_eval(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         id                                    title                                         slug membershipcategory  companytype                                            country                                               logo             telephone                           emailAddress                                            address                                    website
0     38051             A-Mark Precious Metals, Inc.                   a-mark-precious-metals-inc   Affiliate Member       Trader                                                USA                                                      +1 (0) 310 587 1485                      trading@amark.com  2121 Rosecrans Avenue, Suite 6300, El Segundo,...                     https://www.amark.com/
1     38043                              ABC Bullion                                  abc-bullion        Full Member       Trader                                          Australia                                                          +61 2 9231 4511                comms@abcbullion.com.au   Level 6 88 Pitt Street Sydney NSW 2000 Australia             https://www.abcbullion.com.au/
2     38044         ABC Refinery (Australia) Pty Ltd               abc-refinery-australia-pty-ltd        Full Member      Refiner                                          Australia                                                             1300 889 063                   info@abcrefinery.com                12 Meeks Road Marrickville NSW 2204               https://www.abcrefinery.com/
3     38047                                 Agosi AG  allgemeine-gold-und-silberscheideanstalt-ag   Affiliate Member      Refiner                                            Germany  https://cdn.lbma.org.uk/logos/members/_memberL...        +49 7231 960 0                          info@agosi.de          Kanzlerstrasse 17 75175 Pforzheim Germany              https://www.agosi.de/?lang=en
4     38046               Alex Stewart International                   alex-stewart-international   Affiliate Member      Assayer                                     United Kingdom  https://cdn.lbma.org.uk/logos/members/_memberL...  +44 (0) 151 525 1499  analysis@alexstewartinternational.com   Sefton Business Park Netherton Liverpool L30 1RD  https://www.alexstewartinternational.com/
5    261330                    Alfred H Knight Group                        alfred-h-knight-group   Affiliate Member      Assayer                                     United Kingdom                                                     +44 (0) 151 481 5850                 enquiries@ahkgroup.com    Kings Business Park Kings Drive Prescot L34 1PJ                  https://www.ahkgroup.com/
6     38048   Almalyk Mining - Metallurgical Complex         almalyk-mining-metallurgical-complex   Affiliate Member      Refiner                                         Uzbekistan                                                         +998 70 614 3799                           info@agmk.uz                      Amir Temur Str. Amalyk 702400           https://www.agmk.uz/index.php/en
7     38049                           ALS Inspection                               als-inspection   Affiliate Member      Assayer                                     United Kingdom                                                         +44 151 548 7777            info.ukenviro@alsglobal.com                 12 Caddick Road Merseyside L34 9ER                  https://www.alsglobal.com
8     38050            Amalgamated Metal Trading Ltd                amalgamated-metal-trading-ltd        Full Member       Dealer                                     United Kingdom                                                         +44 20 7626 4521                                                             55 BishopsgateLondon EC2N 3AH                      https://www.amt.co.uk
..      ...                                      ...                                          ...                ...          ...                                                ...                                                ...                   ...                                    ...                                                ...                                        ...
147   38181                     Vintage Bullion DMCC                         vintage-bullion-dmcc   Affiliate Member       Trader                               United Arab Emirates  https://cdn.lbma.org.uk/logos/members/_memberL...        +971 4 4468600                mail@vintagebullion.com  39E, Almas Tower, JLT, P.O. Box 111936 Dubai, UAE   https://www.vintagebullion.com/index.php
148   38182       Virtu Financial Global Markets LLC           virtu-financial-global-markets-llc        Full Member       Trader                                                USA  https://cdn.lbma.org.uk/logos/members/_memberL...   +1 (0) 212 588 4000                         info@virtu.com    900 3rd Avenue, 29th Floor, New York, NY, 10022                     https://www.virtu.com/
149   38183  VPower Finance Security (Hong Kong) Ltd        vpower-finance-security-hong-kong-ltd        Full Member  Transporter  Hong Kong (Special Administrative Region of Ch...  https://cdn.lbma.org.uk/logos/members/_memberL...        +852 2772 2666                         cs@v-power.com  703, International Communications Centre, 168 ...                   https://www.v-power.com/
150   38185              Westpac Banking Corporation                  westpac-banking-corporation        Full Member         Bank                                          Australia                                                          +61 2 8204 2870                                           Level 2, 275 Kent StreetSydneyNSW 2000Australia                https://www.westpac.com.au/
151   38186                    WisdomTree UK Limited                        wisdomtree-uk-limited   Affiliate Member          ETF                                     United Kingdom  https://cdn.lbma.org.uk/logos/members/_memberL...      +44 20 7448 4330                                                          3 Lombard Street London EC3V 9AA             https://www.etfsecurities.com/
152   38187            World Gold Trust Services LLC                world-gold-trust-services-llc   Affiliate Member          ETF                                                USA                                                          +1 212 317 3800                          info@gold.org  685 Third Avenue, 27th Floor New York, NY 1001...                       https://www.gold.org
153   38188                  Zaveri &amp; Co Pvt Ltd                            zaveri-co-pvt-ltd   Affiliate Member       Trader                                              India  https://cdn.lbma.org.uk/logos/_memberLogo/2317...      +91 98 7929 8989                                          Swagat Building CG Road Ahmeabad 380.006 Gujurat                 http://WWW.ZAVERIGROUP.COM
154  510537                       ZIEMANN VALOR GmbH                           ziemann-valor-gmbh   Affiliate Member       Trader                                            Germany  https://cdn.lbma.org.uk/logos/_memberLogo/5105...      +49 911 98207010                  info@ziemann-valor.de            Siegelsdorfer Straße 31, 90431 Nürnberg           https://www.ziemann-valor.de/en/
155   38189                     Zürcher Kantonalbank                         zürcher-kantonalbank        Full Member         Bank                                        Switzerland                                                         +41 44 293 61 33                                                           Bahnhofstrasse 9 CH-8010 Zurich                        https://www.zkb.ch/

[156 rows x 11 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution which I got with selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#LBMA website scraping
path = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe'

#create ChromeOptions instance
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

#run Chrome in headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

#initialize the webdriver with the ChromeOptions
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

#navigate to the desired URL
url = 'https://www.lbma.org.uk/membership/current-membership#-'
driver.get(url)

#get the text from web element
search = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'panel.border-collapse.w-full')
data = search.text

#create dataframe
lines = data.split('\n')
columns = ['Company_Name', 'Membership_Category', 'Company_Type', 'Country']
lbma_members = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for line in lines:
    #split line to a list
    lista = line.split(' ')
    #get the key index
    if 'Member' in lista:
        ind = lista.index('Member')

        #get the company name
        company_name = ' '.join(lista[0 : ind-1])
        #get the membership category
        membership_category = ' '.join(lista[ind-1 : ind+1])
        #get the company type
        company_type = lista[ind+1]
        #get the country
        country = ' '.join(lista[ind+2 :])

        new_row = {'Company_Name': company_name, 'Membership_Category': membership_category,
                   'Company_Type': company_type, 'Country': country}
        
        new_row_df = pd.DataFrame([new_row])
        lbma_members = pd.concat([lbma_members, new_row_df], ignore_index=True)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Because what you are getting from the request is the source html. The one you can see using `ctrl+u` on the page(view-source mode).

The website uses javascript to dynamically render the table you are trying to get so it does not appear in the source html.

It seems like the data you are looking for is written in the script section in the `dataset` variable.

If this is not the data you need, you will have to use a package like [pyppeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/) to dynamically navigate the page.